# Checkbox table - equal column widths

Tags: css, html-table, tablelayout

I am struggling with building a table with equal column widths except the first one (only for checkboxes), which should be as small as possible. However the checkbox overflows. Any idea how to fix this? I am doing this:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 600px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: auto;
}

td:first-of-type {
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Long non-important text</td>
    <td>Mid length</td>
    <td>Short</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Long non-important text</td>
    <td>Mid length</td>
    <td>Short</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ht5x1buo/1/) example

Answer (score 1):

For first column, give width in px

```
td:first-of-type {
  width: 20px;
}
```

> If you're creating a component and want this component to use various
>   time with different size of checkbox then take the width of first
>   column from where it is called. For example, if I am using Angular
>   then the code would be
>
> ```
> <app-table [checkboxwidth]="20"></app-table>
> ```
>
> and then set the width of first column to `checkboxwidth`.

Comment: I don't want to hard code it (just in case the checkbox would get bigger)

Comment: @TomasB, according to me, hard code is the better option here. How your checkbox get bigger?

Comment: its a reusable component and user could override it by his own styles - therefore if he wants to change the size of the checkbox he can.